# Family of curve singularities whose generic members are smooth

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, singularity-theory

Let $f: (X,x)\rightarrow (\mathbb C,0)$ be a deformation of a curve singularity $(X_0,x)$, and let $f: X \rightarrow T$ be a sufficiently small representative. Assume that $(X,x)$ is reduced and pure dimensional, and for all $t\in T$, $t\not =0$, the fibers $X_t:=f^{-1}(t)$ are smooth curve singularities. Is it true then that $X_0$ is reduced at $x$?

I have a counterexample for this question in the case $X$ is reduced but not pure-dimensional (for that example, $X_t$ are smooth for all $t\not =0$, but they have two isolated points, whereas $X_0$ has an embedded non-reduced point at $0$).

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding the question: what about e.g. elliptic surfaces with multiple fibres?

Comment: Also, the phrase "smooth curve singularities" is confusing; do you mean that the fibers are smooth?

Comment: @Artie: $f:X \rightarrow T$ has smooth generic fibers who all are curve singularities. The special fiber maybe not smooth, but my question is, whether the smoothness of the generic fibers ensure for the reducedness of the special fiber (together with the pure-dimensionality of $X$, i.e., the generic fibers has no isolated points)?

Comment: Dear @user46910, I suppose I am objecting to saying that a smooth fiber is a "curve singularity". That seems needlessly complicated --- why not just say it is smooth? About your question, I am asserting there are fibred surfaces where the generic fibre is smooth, but some (scheme-theoretic) fibre is nowhere reduced. Is that the kind of example you are looking for?

Comment: To be more precise, e.g., any elliptic pencil on an Enriques surface.

Comment: Dear @Artie: I used "curve singularities" to remark that all fibers should be of dimension 1. Of course, if $X$ is pure dimensional then the generic fiber $X_t$ has no isolated points, and $X_t$ is purely 1-dimensional, then I schould just enough to write "smooth".

Comment: The example of elliptic pencil on an Enriques surface is a counter example of my question in the global case. Thanks Artie Prendergast-Smith and Alex Degtyarev. However, what I am looking for is in local situation, that is, looking for a local family of curve singularities with such a property.

Comment: @Trinh: take the point $p$ in the base over which you have a multiple fibre, and take a neighbourhood of $p$ (in whatever sense you like).

Comment: Thanks Artie. I think for this situation what you have said is true. I shall ask something relating to this topic later (for morphisms whose special fiber has some ebedded points, but its delta-invariant is zero like the delta-invariant of the generic fibers). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $(X,x)$ is reduced and pure dimensional is not enough. For instance, consider $X$ as the union of the two planes $x_1=x_2=0$ and $x_3=x_4=0$ in $\mathbb C^4$ and take $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4$. Then $(X_0,0)$ is not reduced.

It is true when $(X,x)$ is Cohen-Macaulay and the fibre $(X_0,x)$ has isolated singularity. Since $(X,x)$ is Cohen-Macaulay of dimension 2, $(\mathbb C,0)$ is smooth of dimension 1 and the fibre $(X_0,x)$ has dimension 1, the map $f$ is flat. It follows that $f$ is a non zero divisor in the local ring of $(X,x)$ and hence $(X_0,x)$ is also Cohen-Macaulay. Now Serre's criterion $R_0+S_1$ gives that $(X_0,x)$ is reduced.